# The DELETE method is not supported for this route with laravel

Tags: laravel, crud

i'am using laravel in my project , do i want to delete an appointement , but i get this error : The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

This is the controller :

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $rdv = DB::table('rdv')->where('id',$id)->delete();
    
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('success delete !' ) ; 
    }
}
```

this is the form :

```
@if ( $getpat->Etat_de_rdv == 'en_attente') 
<td><label class="badge badge-warning"> {{$getpat->Etat_de_rdv}} </label></td>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('delete', $getpat->id) }}">
 @method('DELETE')
 @csrf
<button type="submit">Supprimer rendez-vous</button>
</form>
```

this is the **web.php**

```
 Route::get('/delete', 'rendezv@destroy')->name('delete');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
Route::delete('/delete/{id}', 'rendezv@destroy')->name('delete');
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `Route::get()`, but supplying `@method('delete')`; those are contradictory. Modify your route as follows:

```
Route::delete('delete', 'rendezv@destroy')->name('delete');
```

Additionally, you're not passing the `$id` parameter, so `route('delete', $getpat->id)` won't work. You can do this with a form field, or a URL parameter:

```
Route::delete('delete/{id}', 'rendezv@destroy')->name('delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct declaration of the route is:

```
Route::delete('/delete', 'rendezv@destroy')->name('delete');
```

Comment: This answer is still wrong; you're missing the `'/{id}'` parameter.